# Different align in IE and chrome (multiple <div> to align center and horizontal)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to align multiple div horizontally.
This is my simple test code.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; display:inline-block;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

It looks well in chrome, but in IE doesn't work like below picture

[image]

Why does it look different from IE and Chrome?
any answers would be thanks.

Comment: Is that picture from explorer?

Comment: yes I edited my question just now. picture from IE

Comment: @LSH I see that you example work perfectly in IE. IE11 on Win10.

Comment: What version of explorer? Working fine for me

Comment: visual studio 2010 was setting IE version 5. I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; display:inline-block; *display: inline;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block; *display: inline;">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource that covers this topic: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Basically IE has a trigger called "hasLayout". Triggering this will allow you to use display:inline-block on a block level element (by default IE only allows inline-block on native inline elements).

Additionally older version of Fire Fox didn't support inline-block either, but had an "inline-stack" value (moz-inline-stack).

Here is, to my knowledge, the best way to get a cross-browser display:inline-block:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```